# Django Model Manager

Tags: django, object, model, django-queryset

I have a Django Model where users can create objects and keep them private for a certain period of time.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    private_until = models.DateField(null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    objects = MyModelManager()
```

In my ListView, I want for visitors only the "non-private" objects to appear and for authenticated users the "non-private" objects plus their own private objects. So my Manager looks like this:

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def include_his_private(self, user):
        if user.is_authenticated:
            include_his_private = super().get_queryset().filter(~Q(private_until__gt=datetime.date.today()))
            include_his_private |= super().get_queryset().filter(Q(creator=user))
            return include_his_private
        else:
            return super().get_queryset().filter(~Q(private_until__gt=datetime.date.today()))

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(~Q(private_until__gt=datetime.date.today()))
```

For my `ListView` this works great. But when I click on an object to get its `DetailView`, I get a 404 error right on "URL-Level". In my URLs I have:

```
    path('<slug:slug>', MyModelDetailView.as_view(), name='mymodel_detail'),
```

... and somehow, Django checks already in advance the whole slug against the per Manager allowed slugs, before I have the chance to pass the user in. What is the way to solve my problem? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
My DetailView looks like this:

```
class MyModelDetailView(DetailView):
     model = MyModel     
     template_name = 'mymodel_detail.html'      

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
         slug = self.kwargs['slug']
         if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            obj = MyModel.objects.include_his_private(self.request.user).get(slug=slug)       
         else:
             obj = MyModel.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) will use the [**`.get_queryset(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) to obtain a queryset and in the [**`.get_object(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object), it will filter on the `pk` and/or `slug` automatically, if a path contains such URL parameters. This is thus done *before* you run the custom logic in the `get_context_data`.

You thus should override the `get_queryset` method:

```
class MyModelDetailView(DetailView):
     model = MyModel     
     template_name = 'mymodel_detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return MyModel.objects.include_his_private(
            self.request.user
        )
```

Comment: Thx a lot! It's so easy, once you see the solution :-/ I thought "get_QuerySet" only makes sense on a ListView :-/

Comment: @zeus: well a `DetailView` basically just constructs extra logic on top of that: it thus will use `get_queryset`, and then perform extra filtering with the slug/pk to retrieve a single object. So it will never process the `get_queryset` as a collection.